# how can i parse a string using c

Tags: c

Given below is my string

```
char test[1000]="$GPGSA,A,3,14,20,22,25,31,32,,,,,,,2.4,1.4,1.9*3A
    $GPGSV,4,1,16,31,76,060,35,14,28,070,34,20,32,309,32,32,61,309,32*72\n
    $GPGSV,4,2,16,25,21,053,29,24,37,258,29,23,14,277,27,12,,,21*44\n
    $GPGSV,4,3,16,22,13,133,20,11,20,272,,16,11,161,,30,,,*4F\
    n$GPGSV,4,4,16,29,,,,28,,,,27,,,,26,,,*7E\n
    $GPGGA,150427.8,4001.022852,N,10505.269674,W,1,06,1.4,1559.6,M,-21.0,M,,*53\n
    $PQXFI,150427.8,4001.022852,N,10505.269674,W,1559.6,35.12,25.46,2.05*4A\n
    $GPVTG,nan,T,nan,M,0.0,N,0.0,K,A*23\n
    $GPRMC,150427.8,A,4001.022852,N,10505.269674,W,0.0,,280611,,,A*50";
```

I want to get string

```
"$GPGGA,150427.8,4001.022852,N,10505.269674,W,1,06,1.4,1559.6,M,-21.0,M,,*53\n"
```

from above big string using C Language.

Please help me out.

Comment: Try [`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html).

Comment: Are all your strings formatted this way, can you just index into the string or are you dealing with different lengths of strings with different line counts, etc? As @Chris Lutz has asked, what have you tried, where are you stuck? I would add, are there more strings like this and you want something fitting a particular format? We need more info. Add more info and I will remove my downvote of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You say which line you want, but you didn't say why. If you say what it is about this line that makes it the line you are after, then I could comment on how you'd find it.

But basically, you'll probably want to separate the string into lines. You can use `strtok()` to break on `\n`. You can then examine the lines, one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like GPS data to me and is used (and parsed) in many applications.

http://mbed.org/users/todotani/notebook/gps-nmea-parser/

http://www.edaboard.com/thread204021.html

You might be able to save yourself some time by re-using some other open source parsers.

Answer (score 1):

The [strstr()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strstr.html) command, part of the standard C library, can be used to find a substring within a string.